# Using MSMTP with GoDaddy relay servers. Help?

Tags: server, php, email

Okay first of all I have done my homework and research on this. Most of the guides that I have found are for setting up MSMTP with Gmail. First let me tell you what I have done so far.

My box is running Ubuntu 12.04. I'm using Zpanel 10.1.1. Since I don't need to to receive emails on my server, I have no need for Postfix which is bundled with the software. So I disabled it at startup using:

```
 sudo update-rc.d postfix disable
```

Before I go any further, the scenario is this. I run multiple websites on this box. They're all Wordpress sites. One of those sites has users sign up but I need it to send confirmation emails. When people receive the emails I need to it say its from "wordpress@mydomain1.com". Then if another website needs to send out an email, I need the email to be received from that websites domain: "wordpress@mydomain2.com". Make sense?

So after I disabled Postfix I installed MSMTP using the command

```
sudo apt-get install msmtp ca-certificates
```

Then I made the config file using the the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/msmtprc
```

Then inside the config file is the following: (Username and Password has been changed)

```
tls on
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
tls_starttls off

account default
host smtpout.asia.secureserver.net
user (my GoDaddy email address)
from (my GoDaddy email address)
password (my GoDaddy password)
port 25
```

Then in the guide I was following it said I had to run the following command:

```
sudo chmod 0644 /etc/msmtprc
```

Then I went into my php.ini file and changed the sendmail path with the following commands:

```
nano /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

Then in the php.ini I changed the sendmail path to this:

```
sendmail_path = "/usr/bin/msmtp -t"
```

Then I did a test with MSMTP from the command line:

```
 echo -e "Subject: Test Mail\r\n\r\nThis is a test mail" |msmtp --debug --from=(GoDaddyEmail) -t (PersonalGmailEmail)
```

With that command it shows me what the server is doing and it shows me any errors that happen:

```
loaded system configuration file /etc/msmtprc
ignoring user configuration file /root/.msmtprc: No such file or directory
falling back to default account
using account default from /etc/msmtprc
host                  = smtpout.asia.secureserver.net
port                  = 25
timeout               = off
protocol              = smtp
domain                = localhost
auth                  = choose
user                  = (GoDaddyEmail)
password              = *
passwordeval          = (not set)
ntlmdomain            = (not set)
tls                   = on  
tls_starttls          = off
tls_trust_file        = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
tls_crl_file          = (not set)
tls_fingerprint       = (not set)
tls_key_file          = (not set)
tls_cert_file         = (not set)
tls_certcheck         = on
tls_force_sslv3       = off
tls_min_dh_prime_bits = (not set)
tls_priorities        = (not set)
auto_from             = off
maildomain            = (not set)
from                  = (GoDaddyEmail)
dsn_notify            = (not set)
dsn_return            = (not set)
keepbcc               = off
logfile               = /root/msmtp.log
syslog                = (not set)
aliases               = (not set)
reading recipients from the command line and the mail
msmtp: TLS handshake failed: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
msmtp: could not send mail (account default from /etc/msmtprc)
```

But none of that is working.. So what am I doing wrong? The server details came from the email setup center within GoDaddy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Upvoting because I learned how to disable postfix.  Thanks.

Comment: Not a problem. Now if I can just figure out how to get MSMTP to work lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue may be the same as I've experienced on other economy hosting.  Try adding this to your msmtprc file.

```
tls_certcheck   off
```

Also, comment this line:

```
tls_trust_file ...
```

Comment: That worked. I'm surprisingly back to this issue almost a year later. This solved my problem logging into the server. Gmail is still rejecting my emails because they're coming from my public IP still, which is weird.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: Yeah I did. I forgot to update this. MSMTP was at fault as it's not handling TLS correctly. Switched to SSMTP, my server is successfully able to login to GoDaddy's SMTP servers and everything is being relayed correctly. 

As a heads up to anyone reading this, make sure to not forget to add ssmtp as your sendmail path in your php.ini file. sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t